# Has many through self join in batmanjs

Tags: has-many-through, self-join, batman.js

I am trying to implement a has many through relationship as elaborated [here](http://rmosolgo.github.io/blog/2014/05/30/has-many-through-in-batman-dot-js/). However, my related model is the same as the referring model by means of a self-join. I tried this:

```
class Article extends Batman.Model
  @hasMany 'citations'
  @hasMany 'usages', name: 'Citation', foreignKey: 'referenced_article_id'

  @accessor 'referenced_articles', ->
    @get('citations').mappedTo('referenced_article')

class Citation extends Batman.Model
  @belongsTo 'article'
  @belongsTo 'referenced_article', name: 'Article'
```

Unfortunately, calling `my_article.get('referenced_articles')` gives an error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, shoot. I didn't add `mappedTo` to `SetProxy` in 0.16. It's fixed with this PR: https://github.com/batmanjs/batman/pull/1052

You could either get master from batmanjs.org/download.html or monkey-patch it with:

```
Batman.AssociationSet::mappedTo = Batman.Set::mappedTo
```

(That's what I was doing til I updated to master)

Sorry!!

Comment: You can download batman/master from the website (http://batmanjs.org/download.html), but it has a few other breaking changes (see https://github.com/batmanjs/batman/issues/1106).

In a pinch, you can just add that line ^^ right before your app definition. That how I fixed it before I fixed it in master.

Answer (score 0):

Since your association is named `usages` (not `citations`), you could try:

```
@accessor 'referenced_articles', ->
  @get('usages').mappedTo('referenced_article')
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. It looks like the `mappedTo` is not defined. The AssociationSet (usages) I am calling it from does have the related items (referenced articles). I also do have the latest version of batman (V0.16.0), so that shouldn't be the problem eighter.